# Can I use regex_t for several compilations

Tags: c, regex

Basic question, not clear to me for the regcomp man.

If I have a static instance of regex_t, can I reuse it for several compilation without freeing it every time, something like:

```
    int match(char* pattern, char* name) {
       static regex_t re;
       regcomp(&re,pattern,REG_EXTENDED|REG_NOSUB);
      ...
    }
```

The code itself is bit more complicated, and the idea is to use static variable to save compilation if the pattern was not changed between calls. The question is if I need to call regfree before each new regcomp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the previous result of `regcomp()` that was compiled into `re` that's perfectly fine - as long as you *don't* call `regfree()` in the meantime.

But when you want to compile a new regex by calling `regcomp()` again, you'll need to call `regfree()` to properly release any resources used by the previous `regcomp()` call.  So you'll probably need some other static variable that keeps track of whether or not the `re` variable has been used by a call to `regcomp()` and needs to be `regfree()`-ed before being reused.

Something along the lines of:

```
int match(char* pattern, char* name) {
   static regex_t re;
   static int re_in_use = 0;

   if (isNewRegex( pattern)) {  // however you want to determine this...
        if (re_in_use) {
            regfree( &re);
            re_in_use = 0;
        }
   }

   re_in_use = regcomp(&re,pattern,REG_EXTENDED|REG_NOSUB);

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I cant write a good explanation, but here is an example code for a one element regcomp() cache:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <regex.h> 

static struct {
  char *pattern;
  regex_t re;
} last_match = { .pattern = (char*)NULL };


int match( const char *pattern, const char *name ){
  int ret;

  if( last_match.pattern != (char*)NULL  &&  strcmp( last_match.pattern, pattern ) != 0 ){
    free( last_match.pattern ); last_match.pattern = (char*)NULL;
    regfree( &last_match.re );
  }

  if( last_match.pattern == (char*)NULL ){
    last_match.pattern = (char*)malloc( strlen(pattern)+1 );
    strcpy( last_match.pattern, pattern );
    ret = regcomp( &last_match.re, last_match.pattern, REG_EXTENDED|REG_NOSUB );
    printf("regcomp: %i  '%s'\n", ret, last_match.pattern );
  }

  ret = regexec( &last_match.re, name, 0, (regmatch_t*)NULL, 0);
  printf("regexec: %i\n", ret );

  return ret;
}

int main(void){
  match( "[0-9]+", "qwer1234" );
  match( "[0-9]+", "asdf5678" );

  match( "[a-z]+", "qwer1234" );
  match( "[a-z]+", "asdf5678" );
}
```

If You run the code You will see two 'regcomp' message and four 'regexec' message because of the regex_t reuse.